# routing URI containing email in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, uri

This is an email activation link written in user controller

http://www.some.com/user/activate_user/user@gmail.com/90101001010

I want to write routes for this.

I tried the below one but its

```
// USER POST
$route['user'] = 'user';
$route['user/activate_user/:any/:num'] = 'user/activate_user/$1/$2';
```

**Error**

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

if i run uri like this it's fine

http://www.some.com/user/activate_user/activate_user/1111/90101001010

why is it not accepting email id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_@-';
$route['user/activate_user/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'user/activate_user/$1/$2'; –
```

Answer (score 2):

should be:

```
$route['user/([\w+-]+)(\.[\w+-]+)*@([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/(:any)']
```

The entire string is a regex without delimiters or modifiers. You were putting delimiters, modifiers and were also using `^` and `$`.

Comment: i tried 

$route['user/activate_user/([\w+-]+)(\.[\w+-]+)*@([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/(:any)'] = 'user/activate_user/$1/$2';


An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-'@&?=; change this

Comment: that gives syntax error due to quotes i changed this
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-@&?=';

error
Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 15

Filename: core/URI.php

Comment: try this $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_@-'; and check http://sholsinger.com/2009/04/passing-email-addresses-in-urls-with-codeigniter

Comment: yes this worked thank you :)

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_@-';

$route['user/activate_user/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'user/activate_user/$1/$2';

Answer (score 1):

Please check your config file, which uri chars are you permitted in the url. by default it is look likes:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';
```

if you want further need please visit the link [Url Guideline by ellislab](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrade_140.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to config.php

Find `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';`

And add `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@&\-!';`

And the stop and or refresh server

Replace This

```
$route['user'] = 'user';
$route['user/activate_user/:any/:num'] = 'user/activate_user/$1/$2';
```

With This

```
$route['user'] = 'user';
$route['user/activate_user/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'user/activate_user/$1/$2';
```

**Added**

[Tutorial Email Activation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmKm1gCgUoM)

Comment: tried this
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-@&?=';

not working

Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 15

Filename: core/URI.php

Comment: I added a tutorial on email activation which it what I use from phpacademy even though it's old version of codeigniter still works fine on codeigniter 3

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

config.php

```
 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_@-';
```

router.php

```
 $route['user/activate_user/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'user/activate_user/$1/$2';
```